# Schedule CronJobs with the PHP Buildpack

Tags: laravel, cron, scheduled-tasks, cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

For my PHP Web App I am using the PHP Buildpack. Now I would like to schedule a Tasks that should be triggered every month. Normally I would use CronJobs for that.
How can I achieve that within the Swisscom Application Cloud?

Comment: We use our Jenkins to trigger task like that.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Have you got some helpful links? I'd really appreciate that.

Comment: Not really, wrote a bit more in a separate answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Swisscom App Cloud is based on [Open Source Cloud Foundry](https://github.com/cloudfoundry)

Upstream Cloud Foundry doesn’t have a feature equivalent to cron jobs (task scheduler). Stay tuned, I guess this feature will be soon implemented, because lots of people migrating from [Heroku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroku) to CF. Heroku offers a cron job feature. Subscribe to Swisscom App Cloud Newsletter to read announcements.

There are workarounds for scheduling tasks, see [Scheduling tasks on Cloud Foundry](https://blog.pivotal.io/pivotal-labs/labs/scheduling-tasks-on-cloud-foundry) on blog.pivotal.io for a Ruby/Rake based example. Sorry for PHP I didn't found example code. There is no elegant solution! You need to implement yourself some kind of workaround. Would be great if you publish your code to GitHub.

If you need cron jobs only in data store, for example MariaDB offers [Events](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/events/).

> Events are named database objects containing SQL statements that are
>   to be executed at a later stage, either once off, or at regular
>   intervals.
>
> They function very similarly to the Windows Task Scheduler or Unix
>   cron jobs.

Answer (score 1):

We had a simular issue. As written by @Fyodor, there is no native solution in Cloud Foundry. We did some research and found vendors like https://www.iron.io/.

Finally, we ended up with a very simple solution.

- We expose all our background jobs via an https interface.
- As we anyhow use Jenkins for CI/CD and it has lots of scheduling capabilities, we use our existing Jenkins to trigger these jobs via a simple cURL call to the HTTP endpoints.

Comment: Thank you! I'll go for this solution as well.